# Can pivot_longer or any R function lead to a tidy dataframe with columns of different types?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Given a survey dataframe in this kind of shape :

| ID | Age_1 | Age_2 | Age_3 | Lang_1_E | Lang_1_F | Lang_2_E | Lang_2_F | Lang_3_E | Lang_3_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 25 | 30 | English | NA | English | NA | English | French |
| 2 | 21 | 25 | 47 | English | French | English | NA | English | French |
| 3 | 17 | 42 | 43 | NA | French | NA | French | NA | French |

where each row represents an interview, and the respondent answers different questions about all his/her family members.

I have to reshape the dataframe so each row represents a person, like that :

| ID | person | Age | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | English | NA |
| 1 | 2 | 25 | English | NA |
| 1 | 3 | 30 | English | French |
| 2 | 1 | 21 | English | French |
| 2 | 2 | 25 | English | NA |
| 2 | 3 | 47 | English | French |
| 3 | 1 | 17 | NA | French |
| 3 | 2 | 42 | NA | French |
| 3 | 3 | 43 | NA | French |

here is the code to create the example dataframe

```
df <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Age_1, ~Age_2, ~Age_3, ~Lang_1_1, ~Lang_1_2, ~Lang_2_1, ~Lang_2_2, ~Lang_3_1, ~Lang_3_2,
  1, 20, 25, 30, "English", NA, "English", NA, "English", "French",
  2, 21, 25, 47, "English", "French", "English", NA, "English", "French",
  3, 17, 42, 43, NA, "French", NA, "French", NA, "French"
)
```

I will be grateful if anyone knows an easy way to achieve this

I tried to gather then to spread again but the fact that there are numeric columns and others in characters complicates things.
Doing it for each question separately and then binding the columns would take forever given the gigantic number of questions in this survey.

Answer (score 1):

`pivot_longer()` will work with a slight modification to the variable names.  Right now, you've got the age variables as `Age_<person>` and the language variables as `Lang_<person>_<language>`.  Normally, you would use a regular expression to find the variable name and long-form obs id (i.e., person in this case).  For example, you might normally do `(.*)_(\\d)` - which would find everything before the last digit and the underscore as the variable name and the last digit as the person identifier. In your case, though, the person identifier is in the middle of the string.  The `setNames()` line in my code is swapping the digit after the first underscore and digit after the second underscore so that the regular expression will work in the appropriate way.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Age_1, ~Age_2, ~Age_3, ~Lang_1_1, ~Lang_1_2, ~Lang_2_1, ~Lang_2_2, ~Lang_3_1, ~Lang_3_2,
  1, 20, 25, 30, "English", NA, "English", NA, "English", "French",
  2, 21, 25, 47, "English", "French", "English", NA, "English", "French",
  3, 17, 42, 43, NA, "French", NA, "French", NA, "French"
)
df %>% 
  setNames(gsub("(.*)_(\\d)_(\\d)", "\\1_\\3_\\2", names(df))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_pattern="(.*)_(\\d)", names_to=c(".value", "person"))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#>      ID person   Age Lang_1  Lang_2
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr> 
#> 1     1 1         20 English <NA>  
#> 2     1 2         25 English <NA>  
#> 3     1 3         30 English French
#> 4     2 1         21 English French
#> 5     2 2         25 English <NA>  
#> 6     2 3         47 English French
#> 7     3 1         17 <NA>    French
#> 8     3 2         42 <NA>    French
#> 9     3 3         43 <NA>    French
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you verry much. 
I just have to find a way to rename the columns so that they follow the same pattern

Comment: Is there a pattern in the column names as they currently exist?

Comment: unfortunately not, there are questions with single answer and others with multiple answers, and the index which represents the mombre is
sometimes right next to the question code: Q1_2_1: member 2, answer option 1
and sometimes at the end of the name: Q9_1_2: answer option 1, member 2.

Comment: Though no doubt all options are suboptimal here, it might be easiest to identify the variables that have different patterns, create a different dataset for each pattern and then rename those variables programmatically to be consistent.  Then you could put all the data back together with `bind_cols()` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I did it with your setNames and gsub trick you’ve showed me  and and I got through it thanks to you, thank you very much bro!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Dave's answer but using `rename_with` and the `names_sep` argument of `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat |> 
  rename_with(~gsub("Lang_(\\d)_(.*)$", "\\2_\\1", .x), starts_with("Lang")) |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c(".value", "person"), names_sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#>      ID person   Age E       F     
#>   <int> <chr>  <int> <chr>   <chr> 
#> 1     1 1         20 English <NA>  
#> 2     1 2         25 English <NA>  
#> 3     1 3         30 English French
#> 4     2 1         21 English French
#> 5     2 2         25 English <NA>  
#> 6     2 3         47 English French
#> 7     3 1         17 <NA>    French
#> 8     3 2         42 <NA>    French
#> 9     3 3         43 <NA>    French
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
             Age_1 = c(20L, 21L, 17L),
             Age_2 = c(25L, 25L, 42L),
             Age_3 = c(30L, 47L, 43L),
          Lang_1_E = c("English", "English", NA),
          Lang_1_F = c(NA, "French", "French"),
          Lang_2_E = c("English", "English", NA),
          Lang_2_F = c(NA, NA, "French"),
          Lang_3_E = c("English", "English", NA),
          Lang_3_F = c("French", "French", "French")
)
```